# google charts bad request

Tags: google-visualization

does anyone know why this is a bad request?

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lxy&
chd=t:0,0.7,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.6,4.3,5,5.8,6.5,7.2,7.9,8.6,9.4,10.1,10.8,11.5,12.2,12.9,13.7,14.4,15.1,15.8,16.5,17.3,18,18.7,19.4,20.1,20.9,21.6,22.3,23,23.7,24.5,25.2,25.9,26.6,27.3,28.1,28.8,29.5,30.2,30.9,31.7,32.4,33.1,33.8,34.5,35.3,36,36.7,37.4,38.1,38.8,39.6,40.3,41,41.7,42.4,43.2,43.9,44.6,45.3,46,46.8,47.5,48.2,48.9,49.6,50.4,51.1,51.8,52.5,53.2,54,54.7,55.4,56.1,56.8,57.6,58.3,59,59.7,60.4,61.2,61.9,62.6,63.3,64,64.7,65.5,66.2,66.9,67.6,68.3,69.1,69.8,70.5,71.2,71.9,72.7,73.4,74.1,74.8,75.5,76.3,77,77.7,78.4,79.1,79.9,80.6,81.3,82,82.7,83.5,84.2,84.9,85.6,86.3,87.1,87.8,88.5,89.2,89.9,90.6,91.4,92.1,92.8,93.5,94.2,95,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.8,98.6,99.3|30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30|0,0.7,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.6,4.3,5,5.8,6.5,7.2,7.9,8.6,9.4,10.1,10.8,11.5,12.2,12.9,13.7,14.4,15.1,15.8,16.5,17.3,18,18.7,19.4,20.1,20.9,21.6,22.3,23,23.7,24.5,25.2,25.9,26.6,27.3,28.1,28.8,29.5,30.2,30.9,31.7,32.4,33.1,33.8,34.5,35.3,36,36.7,37.4,38.1,38.8,39.6,40.3,41,41.7,42.4,43.2,43.9,44.6,45.3,46,46.8,47.5,48.2,48.9,49.6,50.4,51.1,51.8,52.5,53.2,54,54.7,55.4,56.1,56.8,57.6,58.3,59,59.7,60.4,61.2,61.9,62.6,63.3,64,64.7,65.5,66.2,66.9,67.6,68.3,69.1,69.8,70.5,71.2,71.9,72.7,73.4,74.1,74.8,75.5,76.3,77,77.7,78.4,79.1,79.9,80.6,81.3,82,82.7,83.5,84.2,84.9,85.6,86.3,87.1,87.8,88.5,89.2,89.9,90.6,91.4,92.1,92.8,93.5,94.2,95,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.8,98.6,99.3|28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28|0,0.7,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.6,4.3,5,5.8,6.5,7.2,7.9,8.6,9.4,10.1,10.8,11.5,12.2,12.9,13.7,14.4,15.1,15.8,16.5,17.3,18,18.7,19.4,20.1,20.9,21.6,22.3,23,23.7,24.5,25.2,25.9,26.6,27.3,28.1,28.8,29.5,30.2,30.9,31.7,32.4,33.1,33.8,34.5,35.3,36,36.7,37.4,38.1,38.8,39.6,40.3,41,41.7,42.4,43.2,43.9,44.6,45.3,46,46.8,47.5,48.2,48.9,49.6,50.4,51.1,51.8,52.5,53.2,54,54.7,55.4,56.1,56.8,57.6,58.3,59,59.7,60.4,61.2,61.9,62.6,63.3,64,64.7,65.5,66.2,66.9,67.6,68.3,69.1,69.8,70.5,71.2,71.9,72.7,73.4,74.1,74.8,75.5,76.3,77,77.7,78.4,79.1,79.9,80.6,81.3,82,82.7,83.5,84.2,84.9,85.6,86.3,87.1,87.8,88.5,89.2,89.9,90.6,91.4,92.1,92.8,93.5,94.2,95,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.8,98.6,99.3|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|0,0.7,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.6,4.3,5,5.8,6.5,7.2,7.9,8.6,9.4,10.1,10.8,11.5,12.2,12.9,13.7,14.4,15.1,15.8,16.5,17.3,18,18.7,19.4,20.1,20.9,21.6,22.3,23,23.7,24.5,25.2,25.9,26.6,27.3,28.1,28.8,29.5,30.2,30.9,31.7,32.4,33.1,33.8,34.5,35.3,36,36.7,37.4,38.1,38.8,39.6,40.3,41,41.7,42.4,43.2,43.9,44.6,45.3,46,46.8,47.5,48.2,48.9,49.6,50.4,51.1,51.8,52.5,53.2,54,54.7,55.4,56.1,56.8,57.6,58.3,59,59.7,60.4,61.2,61.9,62.6,63.3,64,64.7,65.5,66.2,66.9,67.6,68.3,69.1,69.8,70.5,71.2,71.9,72.7,73.4,74.1,74.8,75.5,76.3,77,77.7,78.4,79.1,79.9,80.6,81.3,82,82.7,83.5,84.2,84.9,85.6,86.3,87.1,87.8,88.5,89.2,89.9,90.6,91.4,92.1,92.8,93.5,94.2,95,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.8,98.6,99.3|100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100&
chco=3072F3,ff0000,00aaaa,541269&chs=1000x200&chxt=x,y&
chxl=0:|18|18|18|18|18|19|19|19|19|19|19|20|20|20|20|20|20|21|21|21|21|21|21|22|22|22|22|22|22|23|23|23|23|23|23|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|1|1|1|1|2|2|2|2|2|2|3|3|3|3|3|3|4|4|4|4|4|4|5|5|5|5|5|5|6|6|6|6|6|6|7|7|7|7|7|7|8|8|8|8|8|8|9|9|9|9|9|9|10|10|10|10|10|10|11|11|11|11|11|11|12|12|12|12|12|12|13|13|13|13|13|13|14|14|14|14|14|14|15|15|15|15|15|15|16|16|16|16|16|16|17|17|1:||3.5|7|10.5|14
```

trying to plot four lines on a graph

thanks

Comment: Do you have simpler examples  (maybe just one line) that work?

Answer (score 7):

Google Charts has a maximum length of URL that it will handle without giving that error. I'm not sure what that limit is precisely, but your URL is 4774 characters long and I think the limit is just over 2000 characters.

You may need to use the simple or extended data encoding instead of text encoding. Text encoding is the least space-efficient way of encoding data for the Google Charts API. See the [Data Formats](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/formats.html) API documentation for more information.

Comment: +1 the limit is 2k for GET. Use POST which handles 16k ... see http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/post_requests.html

Answer (score 3):

As Greg said, your URL is too long.

> The maximum length of a URL is not determined by the Google Chart API, but rather by web browser and web server considerations. Currently, URLs that are over 2048 characters in length when URL-encoded (e.g., | becomes %7C) are not recommended. As web browsers and servers evolve, this number may change. See http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html for a more in-depth discussion.

Have a look at the [Google Chart API FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/faq.html#url_length) for more information

Comment: +1 the limit is 2k for GET. Use POST which handles 16k ... see http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/post_requests.html

Answer (score 0):

Although this is already answered correctly I thought it might be useful to provide a practical solution using your data:

```
<form id='graphform' name='graphform' action='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart' method='POST' target='graph_target'>
  <input type="hidden" name="cht" value='lxy' /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="chd" value="t:0,0.7,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.6,4.3,5,5.8,6.5,7.2,7.9,8.6,9.4,10.1,10.8,11.5,12.2,12.9,13.7,14.4,15.1,15.8,16.5,17.3,18,18.7,19.4,20.1,20.9,21.6,22.3,23,23.7,24.5,25.2,25.9,26.6,27.3,28.1,28.8,29.5,30.2,30.9,31.7,32.4,33.1,33.8,34.5,35.3,36,36.7,37.4,38.1,38.8,39.6,40.3,41,41.7,42.4,43.2,43.9,44.6,45.3,46,46.8,47.5,48.2,48.9,49.6,50.4,51.1,51.8,52.5,53.2,54,54.7,55.4,56.1,56.8,57.6,58.3,59,59.7,60.4,61.2,61.9,62.6,63.3,64,64.7,65.5,66.2,66.9,67.6,68.3,69.1,69.8,70.5,71.2,71.9,72.7,73.4,74.1,74.8,75.5,76.3,77,77.7,78.4,79.1,79.9,80.6,81.3,82,82.7,83.5,84.2,84.9,85.6,86.3,87.1,87.8,88.5,89.2,89.9,90.6,91.4,92.1,92.8,93.5,94.2,95,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.8,98.6,99.3|30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30|0,0.7,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.6,4.3,5,5.8,6.5,7.2,7.9,8.6,9.4,10.1,10.8,11.5,12.2,12.9,13.7,14.4,15.1,15.8,16.5,17.3,18,18.7,19.4,20.1,20.9,21.6,22.3,23,23.7,24.5,25.2,25.9,26.6,27.3,28.1,28.8,29.5,30.2,30.9,31.7,32.4,33.1,33.8,34.5,35.3,36,36.7,37.4,38.1,38.8,39.6,40.3,41,41.7,42.4,43.2,43.9,44.6,45.3,46,46.8,47.5,48.2,48.9,49.6,50.4,51.1,51.8,52.5,53.2,54,54.7,55.4,56.1,56.8,57.6,58.3,59,59.7,60.4,61.2,61.9,62.6,63.3,64,64.7,65.5,66.2,66.9,67.6,68.3,69.1,69.8,70.5,71.2,71.9,72.7,73.4,74.1,74.8,75.5,76.3,77,77.7,78.4,79.1,79.9,80.6,81.3,82,82.7,83.5,84.2,84.9,85.6,86.3,87.1,87.8,88.5,89.2,89.9,90.6,91.4,92.1,92.8,93.5,94.2,95,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.8,98.6,99.3|28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28|0,0.7,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.6,4.3,5,5.8,6.5,7.2,7.9,8.6,9.4,10.1,10.8,11.5,12.2,12.9,13.7,14.4,15.1,15.8,16.5,17.3,18,18.7,19.4,20.1,20.9,21.6,22.3,23,23.7,24.5,25.2,25.9,26.6,27.3,28.1,28.8,29.5,30.2,30.9,31.7,32.4,33.1,33.8,34.5,35.3,36,36.7,37.4,38.1,38.8,39.6,40.3,41,41.7,42.4,43.2,43.9,44.6,45.3,46,46.8,47.5,48.2,48.9,49.6,50.4,51.1,51.8,52.5,53.2,54,54.7,55.4,56.1,56.8,57.6,58.3,59,59.7,60.4,61.2,61.9,62.6,63.3,64,64.7,65.5,66.2,66.9,67.6,68.3,69.1,69.8,70.5,71.2,71.9,72.7,73.4,74.1,74.8,75.5,76.3,77,77.7,78.4,79.1,79.9,80.6,81.3,82,82.7,83.5,84.2,84.9,85.6,86.3,87.1,87.8,88.5,89.2,89.9,90.6,91.4,92.1,92.8,93.5,94.2,95,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.8,98.6,99.3|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|0,0.7,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.6,4.3,5,5.8,6.5,7.2,7.9,8.6,9.4,10.1,10.8,11.5,12.2,12.9,13.7,14.4,15.1,15.8,16.5,17.3,18,18.7,19.4,20.1,20.9,21.6,22.3,23,23.7,24.5,25.2,25.9,26.6,27.3,28.1,28.8,29.5,30.2,30.9,31.7,32.4,33.1,33.8,34.5,35.3,36,36.7,37.4,38.1,38.8,39.6,40.3,41,41.7,42.4,43.2,43.9,44.6,45.3,46,46.8,47.5,48.2,48.9,49.6,50.4,51.1,51.8,52.5,53.2,54,54.7,55.4,56.1,56.8,57.6,58.3,59,59.7,60.4,61.2,61.9,62.6,63.3,64,64.7,65.5,66.2,66.9,67.6,68.3,69.1,69.8,70.5,71.2,71.9,72.7,73.4,74.1,74.8,75.5,76.3,77,77.7,78.4,79.1,79.9,80.6,81.3,82,82.7,83.5,84.2,84.9,85.6,86.3,87.1,87.8,88.5,89.2,89.9,90.6,91.4,92.1,92.8,93.5,94.2,95,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.8,98.6,99.3|100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="chco" value="3072F3,ff0000,00aaaa,541269" />
  <input type='hidden' name='chs' value='1000x200' />
  <input type="hidden" name="chxt" value="x,y" />
  <input type="hidden" name="chxl" value="0:|18|18|18|18|18|19|19|19|19|19|19|20|20|20|20|20|20|21|21|21|21|21|21|22|22|22|22|22|22|23|23|23|23|23|23|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|1|1|1|1|2|2|2|2|2|2|3|3|3|3|3|3|4|4|4|4|4|4|5|5|5|5|5|5|6|6|6|6|6|6|7|7|7|7|7|7|8|8|8|8|8|8|9|9|9|9|9|9|10|10|10|10|10|10|11|11|11|11|11|11|12|12|12|12|12|12|13|13|13|13|13|13|14|14|14|14|14|14|15|15|15|15|15|15|16|16|16|16|16|16|17|17|1:||3.5|7|10.5|14" />
</form>  
<iframe name='graph_target' src='' style='width:1000px;height:200px;'></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms["graphform"].submit();
</script>
```

This generates a rather uninformative graph!